# fineuploader Upload files with folder structure

Tags: fine-uploader

I want to upload entire folder structure with files in it. 
In file uploader I can drag n drop a folder and it uploads all files in that folder and also the subfolder. But I am not able to get the folder structure on clients machine so that I can mantain it on server.

Does fineuploader give the source folder name of clients machine like we have in chrome's "webkitdirectory"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking for the file path to be sent along with the requests (when uploading an entire folder via DnD) there is [an open case in the Fine Uploader issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/750) that you should have a look at.  Long story short, this is currently only possible when dropping a file (or directory) into Chrome, and not when selecting files via the file chooser dialog due to [a bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138987) that prevents access to associated `FileEntry` objects when handling files submitted via a file input.

The Fine Uploader feature request I referenced has been on hold, but I am happy to put it back in the "to-work" queue if enough users tell me that passing path attributes for files via DnD only is useful.  Feel free to add your comments to that case.

Comment: I would be interested if this ever becomes possible in a browser other than chrome. I don't suppose this case has moved on since July?

Comment: It is now possible in Opera 15+ as well.